# Need to get distance between source (latitude and longitude) and destination (latitude and longitude) using google API

Tags: rest-api, salesforcedx, developer, google-map

Hi I need to calculate the distance of the first location to the second location using google MAP API but I am getting this Error [System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]]. I have tried the below code. please help me where I am doing wrong.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
Http http = new Http();
req.setMethod('GET');
String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json' + '?origins=' + recordName.Checked_In_Location__Latitude__s,recordName.Checked_In_Location__Longitude__s + '&destinations=' + recordName.Checked_Out_Location__Latitude__s,recordName.Checked_Out_Location__Longitude__s + '&mode=driving' + '&sensor=false' + '&language=en' + '&units=imperial';
//I have also tried this but did not work.
//String url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=*API Name*';
req.setEndPoint(url);
HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req); 
system.debug('resp====>' + resp);
```

Please share with me any link(I have tried google itself) or reference from I can get help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not separate your latitude and longitude with coma, need to be: `recordName.Checked_Out_Location__Latitude__s + ',' + recordName.Checked_Out_Location__Longitude__s`

The same goes for destination location too.

Comment: Hey Mariia, Thanks for your quick reply. It worked...I got a response. could you please tell me why I am getting this error despite using a paid API - "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",

Comment: Probably, you do not set authorization header in GET request, please, read the documentation Google provides.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it